# How to build a cython wrapper for c++ function with stl list parameter

Tags: python, c++, stl, cython

Consider the following simple c++ code.
(printlist.h)

```
#ifndef TESTLIB_H
#define TESTLIB_H

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void printlist(std::list<int> &);

#endif
```

(printlist.c)

```
#include "printlist.h"

using namespace std;

void printlist(list<int> &l)
  {
  for(list<int>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
  cout << *i << ' ';
  cout << endl;
  }
```

My question is how to use this code with cython, the difficulty being the fact that printlist
takes a stl::list.  Is there a way to declare this using "extern"?  If not, what is the simplest way to use this function.

## This is my attempt:

(test.pyx)

```
 from libcpp.list cimport list

 cdef extern from "printlist.h":
         void printlist(std::list<int> &)

 cdef list[int] l = range(10)
 printlist(l)
```

(setup.py)

```
 from distutils.core import setup
 from distutils.extension import Extension
 from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

 ext_modules = [Extension("test", ["test.pyx", "printlist.C"], language='c++',)]

 setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from libcpp.list cimport list

cdef extern from "printlist.h":
        void printlist(std::list<int> &)
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:4:27: Expected an identifier or literal
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two primary issues with your code.

The first one is that you are using C++ in a C file.
Start by renaming `printlist.c` to `printlist.cpp`

The second is that when you define the calling signature for the external function you use the C++ syntax for the function declaration instead of using braces for class templates as is described at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates .
This is what is causing the error you are seeing.
The line

```
void printlist(std::list<int> &)
```

should be replaced by

```
void printlist(list[int] &)
```

You seem to have done this correctly later in the Cython file when declaring a new list.

Another thing that is worth noting is that Cython files are not executed upon compilation.
It might be easier to wrap your test case in a function that is callable from Python.
Here is a working example.

`printlist.h` (This is the same as yours)

```
#ifndef TESTLIB_H
#define TESTLIB_H

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void printlist(std::list<int> &);

#endif
```

`printlist.cpp` (I only changed the file extension and the spacing)

```
#include "printlist.h"

using namespace std;

void printlist(list<int> &l){
    for(list<int>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << ' ';
    cout << endl;}
```

`test.pyx`
Notice that Cython can convert automatically from a Python list to a C++ list.
I'm doing this in the typing of the arguments for the `list_test` function.
It also supports some other types of automated conversions as is mentioned at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

```
from libcpp.list cimport list

cdef extern from "printlist.h":
    void printlist(list[int] &)

def list_test(list[int] l):
    printlist(l)
```

`setup.py` (I changed the file extension here as well)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("test", ["test.pyx", "printlist.cpp"], language='c++',)]

setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

`test.py`
This is a Python script to call the `list_test` function I added to `test.pyx`.

```
from test import list_test

list_test([1, 2, 3])
```

When run, it should print the string "1 2 3".